# get value from Parse Object in Xamarin

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin

I'm trying to get a value (firstName) from a Parse Object in Xamarin.

I've tried the following but get the error there is no definition for "Get".

Any thoughts? I appreciate the time and expertise.

**My query**

```
async void GetLegacies() {
            var query = ParseObject.GetQuery
("Legacy").WhereEqualTo("objectId", "EVw5ziGIIb");
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
            var count = await query.CountAsync();
            string firstName = results.Get<string>("firstName");
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.WriteLine (firstName);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
```

`results` is a collection of `ParseObject`, not a single result.  You should try

```
IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
List<ParseObject> list = results.ToList();
```

then

```
list[0].Get<string>("firstName");
```

to get the value for the first element in the results

Comment: Just tried the code and get the error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<Parse.ParseObject>"(CS0021)  I appreciate the feedback

Comment: I tried the revised version (changed "results" to "results List" since "results" was already being used and gave me an error) and I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Parse.ParseObject>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Parse.ParseObject>'.

Comment: I'm doing this from memory, so excuse the issues.  See the edit (again).  Be sure you have "using System.Linq;" in your using block

Comment: is there any way to do something like this: list.Count.Where<string>("firstName"); i cant figure out how to do it, thanks